# Github to publish jquery plugins

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, github

Hello.

I programmed a plug-in for `Jquery` but I found out if I want to publish it in `jquery.com` I have to get git-hub anyway I followed all this steps here.
http://plugins.jquery.com/docs/publish/

when I was in the step (Publishing a Version) I didn't know what is mean, I tried to upload my plug-in to `git hub` I didn't know how to do it so please can you help me to finish the last step and publish my plug-in also I didn't know where I put this tags

```
$ git tag 0.1.0
$ git push origin --tags
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `$ git push origin --tags` is not correct.
Use the below command:

```
$ git push --tags origin
```

Refences:
[How do you push a Git tag to a branch using a refspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061481/git-push-tag-master)

http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-6.html

Comment: yeah but please tell me where i can enter this command and how i upload my jquery plugin?

Comment: @WalidNaceri go to https://github.com/ and create the account and use steps given in the link mention by you in the question.

Comment: yeah i have account and i did all the steps but only the problem is the tags i don't know where i put the tag and where i upload the file

Comment: @WalidNaceri do you have the knowledge of svn? and do you have the knowledge of git svn. this command is used to send the data from your local machine to github.

Comment: ohh no :( i don't have the knowledge and i'm using ubuntu i looked  for a tut but they didn't mention how i add my repo and how i connect to it

Comment: @WalidNaceri I think you should studied the the GIT svn and its command to send your library on github. and surely after that you will be able to send it on jquery official site.